# GAEのPaginationについて

Tags: google-app-engine

お世話になっております。
現在GAEでPagination処理をしているのですが、offsetはDatastore Readの回数や、指定できる数値に制限があるのでCursorを使用してPaginationをしようと思っています。

そこで質問なのですが、Cursorは次のページは取得できるのですが、任意のページを取得したい場合、offsetが指定できないのでどのようにすればいいのか困っています。

例えば10ページのコンテンツがあるとして、4ページ目のコンテンツを取得する方法が知りたいです。Cursorを拡張する方法も考えたのですが、filan classのようでできません。

宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: 例えば10ページのコンテンツがあるとして、とありますがこの10ページは datastore の count から計算していたりするのでしょうか？ datastore の count,offset処理は総なめなので処理時間が件数に比例します(count=1とcount=100では処理時間が100倍長くなる。)。GAEは１リクエストの処理時間に制限があるぐらい、線形で処理時間が伸びるのはよくなく、count,offsetは使わないルールを用意したほうが現実的かと思います。どうしてもやりたいなら cloud sql を使ったほうがいいです。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
countも総なめなのですね。offsetはそのような情報を得ておりましたので、使わないでCursorにしようとしていました。
Cloud SQLは盲点でした。ただ、料金が発生することを考えるとできるだけDatastoreで済ませたいとの考えもあります。。。

Answer (score 1):

DatastoreでPaginationするの結構難しいですねー。
僕は大抵UIをReadMoreにしてしまって、Paginationは作っていません。

作るとすれば
1ページ20件で、30ページぐらいまでしか、ほとんど見ることが無いという状況なら、Query.KeysOnlyで、500件ぐらい取ってきて、メモリ上で指定されたページまで読み飛ばす感じでしょうか。
パフォーマンスを向上させるために、一度検索したら、条件とCursorをMemcacheに入れておくと、データが変わらない限りは、Memcacheから持ってこれます。

Comment: 早速の回答ありがとうございます。
ReadMoreはTwitterやQiitaのようなスクロール形式のページングでしょうか？

なるほど、KeysOnlyで取得することでReadのコストは下がりそうですね。Memcacheに関してあまり知識がないのですが、キャッシュしておくのもいいですね。
参考にします。

Comment: ReadMoreはお察しの通り、TwitterやQiitaのようなスクロール形式のページングですね。

Answer (score 0):

bootstrapのページネーションのようなページ番号ボタンを出して直接指定ページにとぶのは処理時間の関係できついですよね。
Cursorのstartとクエリlimitを使ってキーだけのクエリを2回呼べば、前のページと次のページがあるかどうかを判断できますので、次へボタンと前へボタン（活性非活性つき）でのページングは実現できます。

```
// 現在のページを検索
Query<Store> query = ofy().load().type(T.class).order("-created").limit(limit).startAt(cursor);

Cursor nextCursor = 現在のページの最後の行のCursor

// 前のページを逆順で検索
QueryKeys<T> prevQuery = ofy().load().type(T.class).order("created")
                .limit(limit).startAt(Cursor.fromWebSafeString(cursor))
                .keys();

// 次のページがあるかを検索
ofy().load().type(T.class).order("-created")
            .startAt(Cursor.fromWebSafeString(nextCursor)).limit(1)
            .keys().iterator().hasNext()
```